# Smiley face when assigning improper value type to struct property!

Tags: c++, struct, types, variable-assignment

I am somewhat wondering if I am losing my mind, but I swear to you, this code outputs smiley faces as the .name values!! what in the world is going on? Thus far it seems to only work when the value is 1, anything else properly gives errors.

*I realize the code is flawed -> I do not need help with this.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
using namespace tr1;


struct CollectedData
{
public:
    string name;
    float grade;

};

int main()
{
    string line;
    list<CollectedData> AllData;
    int count;

    ifstream myFile("test_data.txt");
    if (myFile.fail()) {cout << "Error opening file"; return 0;}
    else
    {
        cout << "File opened... \n";
        while( getline(myFile, line) ) {
            CollectedData lineData;
            lineData.name = 1;
            lineData.grade = 2;
            AllData.push_back(lineData);
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n File contents: \n";

    list<CollectedData>::iterator Iterator;
    for(Iterator = AllData.begin(); 
            Iterator != AllData.end();
            Iterator++)
    {
        cout << "\t" << (*Iterator).name << " - ";
        cout << "\t" << (*Iterator).grade << "\n";
    }


    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

[:-) http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4600/capturekjc.jpg](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4600/capturekjc.jpg)

**I KNOW THAT THE CODE IS USELESS, 

I WANT TO KNOW WHY IT IS GIVING ME SMILEY FACES INSTEAD OF ERRORS**

*comforting. . . mocking*

Comment: That smiley is the character 0x01.

Comment: +1, situation and minor rage over it made me laugh.

Comment: Code table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smiling face is the character with ASCII value 1. Not sure why, but apparently your compiler decided to treat it as a char, so you get the smiley.

Comment: The smiley face is not an ASCII character.  It is in the IBM-PC (MS-DOS code page 437) set.

Answer (score 9):

> I WANT TO KNOW WHY IT IS GIVING ME SMILEY FACES INSTEAD OF ERRORS

Because the datatype is `string`, and the char `0x01` prints a smile-face. You possibly what to assign the value `0x31` instead, which is the character `1`, in ASCII.

Comment: Or the value `'1'`, which is a portable way of writing the character 1

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
lineData.name = 1;
lineData.grade = 2;
```

I should note that the symbols you're getting are ASCII 1 (ie, exactly what you're setting lineData.name to).

> `while( getline(myFile, line) )`

You need to take the line and parse it, inserting a proper string into lineData.name, and inserting an integer into lineData.grade.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with null termination.

Comment: I assumed from "faces" that there were multiple, one after the other. It would appear that's a bad assumption upon rereading the question, so I've edited the answer.

Comment: Also, when I posted I was behind a proxy which was blocking the image. So I made do with the information I had.

Answer (score 3):

The string is being assigned a character value (1), which happens to be a smiley face in the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said name is of type string, so it would be best to assign a string to it:

```
lineData.name = "1";
```

the inverted commas will let the compiler know that this value is a string, and you will stop getting smiley faces.

that said...

Coolest. Bug. Ever.